# Laravel-5.5:How to add message date in sender time zone and show me in my time zone how gmail?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I've been creating a small mail and there is a date of sending a message. I have to add a message so that everything is correctly displayed in all time zones. What do I need to do to solve such issue problems with dates? You can see my migrations code.

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('subject', 255)->nullable($value = false);
$table->text('message')->nullable($value = false);
$table->integer('sender')->nullable($value = false);
$table->tinyInteger('recipient')->nullable($value = false);
$table->tinyInteger('seen')->default(0);
$table->tinyInteger('show')->default(0);
$table->tinyInteger('trashed')->default(0);
$table->timestampTz('created_at');
$table->timestampTz('updated_at');
```

For example I want to send a message. I have my time zone (GMT +5) and the other user has his own time zone. It is necessary to add the message in my time zone (if I am the sender myself). To the user who received the message you need to show the date of sending the message in your time zone. How does the date on the gmail messages usually work, for example?

Comment: Explain more plz

Comment: You are not seriously from the USA I hope?

Comment: My time zone GMT +5

Comment: For example I from Asia and you from USA. And messages muts be displayed correctly in other time zones